# Fetch data parse textfile

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse a log file that generates in text. I want to retrieve a name and phone number.
Sometimes the info is not there and should be blank.

All examples I've seen tell me how to get the start of a string or end of a string but not what's inside.

Above there is a sample code I've been working with

```
  {
       public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using(TextReader reader = new StreamReader("c:/ctb.txt"))
        {
            string line;                       
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Get the contents of 'per_full_name' [str] = "Smith, John"
                // which would be Smith, John
                // Get the contents of 'per_phone' [str] = "1 555 555-8888"
                // which would be 1 555 555-8888
                // Note this exists atleast twice in the file, I only need
                // Once into a string to be able to make textBox.
                // Text values change.
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Example  text file data:

it is a text file, the format is unknown to me, i beleive its a java output for its own logfile.

```
[str] = "BI Shared Expense" 'org_level4_name' [str] = "Business      International Ins" 'org_level4_oid' [str] = "Business" 'per_first_name' [str] = "" 'per_full_name' [str] = "Smith, John" 'per_last_name' [str] = "" 'per_middle_name' str] = "" 'per_phone' [str] = "1 555 555-8888" 'qpriority' [str] = "norm"
```

VERY long lines of text when not wordwrapped.

The output I'd like is the full name to a string. To be able to use in other functions.

IE:

```
          string fullname = "Smith, John";
```

---

Trying this code now.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/ctb.txt"))
        {

            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(line, "/\\[(str)\\]\\ = \"\\w+\\, +\\w+\"/g"))
            {
                textBox1.Text = m.Value;
                richTextBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

Using this page to get the string but its wanting escapes in the actual program. 
http://www.regexr.com/3bqll

This locates only 'per_full_name' [str] = "Smith, John"

Comment: Need to know the format of the file? Is it csv? Can you post some example lines?

Comment: Please show some input/output

Comment: Maybe it is not the best of ideas to parse a file in the event halder method. If possible, you might want to do this asynchronously.

Comment: [edit] your question and put file content in it. Don't paste it in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using regular expression specally with Phone numbers. C# has a class called Regex which provide functions to search particular and dynamic strings.

This site will help you to build youre regular expression. http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

An Example if youre phonenumber follows this syntax:
 1 555 555-8888
you could use this :
         \d{1}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}-\d{4} Or \d{2,*}(-\s)\d{*}

Comment: Could be a bit of an overkill depending on the format of the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the following, thanks for suggestion to look in to regex.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/ctb.txt"))
        {

            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(line, "\\[(str)\\]\\ = \"\\w+\\, +\\w+\""))
            {
                string name = m.Value.Replace("[str] = \"", "");
                name = name.Replace("\"", "");
                textBox1.Text = name;
            }

        }
        using (StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader("C:/contacttoolbar.txt"))
        {
            String line = sr2.ReadToEnd();
            foreach (Match m2 in Regex.Matches(line, "\\[(str)\\]\\ = \"\\d\\s\\d{3}\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}\""))
            {
                string tele = m2.Value.Replace("[str] = \"", "");
                tele = tele.Replace("\"", "");
                textBox2.Text = tele;
            }
        }
    }
```

This will initially locate in the regex search - [str] = "Smith, John"
Then i parse it down to remove the str part and then the " at the end. giving the output that i want.

resulting in **Smith, John**

The same applies in the telephone number.

resulting in **1 555 555-5555**

I know its two reads of the file but its a small file. relatively.